# Quasi-Group represented by a graph which is not a Triangle-Free Graph locally

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, quasigroups

Can each of all quasi-groups  be represented by  a graph (latin square graph), which is not     locally triangle free graph ?

Quasi Group can be represented by Latin Square matrix, thus by a Latin Square graph.

If all vertices in $G$ have [neighbourhoods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbourhood_%28graph_theory%29) that are isomorphic to the same graph $H$, then $G$ is said to be locally $H$.